# Proof that $(x,y)\sim (x',y') \iff x=x' , y-y'=n2\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$ is an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

Have I made any mistakes in the following proof?

**THEOREM**:

If $P=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x>0 \}$ and if there exists a relation $$\sim|(x,y)\sim(x',y') \iff x=x' , y-y'=n2\pi$$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$ then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $P$.

**PROOF**:

If $(x,y)\sim(x,y)$ then $x=x$ and $y-y=0$ .

Since for all $x\in \mathbb R, x=x$ and $0=n$ in $n2\pi$, $\sim$ is reflexive.

Now if $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$ then $x=x', y-y'=n2\pi$ so if $(x',y')\sim(x,y)$
then $x'=x , y'-y=-n2\pi$  since $-n\in \mathbb Z$, $\sim$ is symmetric.

If  $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$ and $(x',y')\sim(x'',y'')$ then

$x=x'$ and $x'= x''$ and $y-y'=n2\pi$  and  $y'-y''=n'2\pi$. So $x=x''$ by the transitivity of $=$ and $y-y''= (n-n')2\pi$ and $(n-n')\in\mathbb Z$. So, $\sim$ is transitive.

Therefore $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $P$.

QED

How would I show that that each equivalence class contains a unique pair $(x,y)$ with $0\leq y<2\pi$?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You've got the right idea, it's just a little turned around. To show reflexivity, first show that $x=x$ and $y-y=n2\pi$; this implies $(x,y) \sim (x,y)$. Similarly, show that $x=x$' implies $x'=x$ and $y-y'=n2\pi$ implies $y'-y=m2\pi$ for some $m$; then state that this means $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ Transitivity is shown similarly.

Comment: @tarnation Reflexivity and transitivity look OK, but yeah there is a hiccup in symmetry.

Comment: why ? (the  hiccup )

Comment: How would I show that that each equivalence class contains a unique pair (x,y) with 0≤y<2π?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proofs of reflexivity and transitivity are basically okay, though they could be stated a little better, but there is indeed a hiccup in the proof of symmetry. Here’s what you have:

> Now if $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$ then $x=x', y-y'=n2\pi$ so if $(x',y')\sim(x,y)$
>   then $x'=x$, $y'-y=-n2\pi$ since $-n\in \mathbb Z$, $\sim$ is symmetric.

Look at the logical structure: if $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$, then (something), so if $(x',y')\sim(x,y)$, then (something else). That isn’t the structure of the statement of symmetry: you should be proving that if $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$, then $(x',y')\sim(x,y)$. You have all of the pieces needed to do this; you just haven’t put them together correctly. Here’s one way to do that:

> If $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$, then by definition $x=x'$ and $y-y'=2n\pi$ for some integer $n$. But then $y'-y=2(-n)\pi$, and $-n$ is also an integer, so $x'=x$ and $y'-y=2(-n)\pi$ with $-n$ an integer, and therefore by definition $(x',y')\sim(x,y)$. Therefore $\sim$ is symmetric.

To show that each equivalence class contains a unique pair $(x,y)$ with $0\le y<2\pi$, you must show two things: that each equivalence class contains **at least** one such pair, and that each equivalence class contains **at most** one such pair. It’s often easier in such arguments to prove uniqueness (at most one), so let’s start there.

Suppose that $0\le y,y'< 2\pi$ and that $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ are in the same equivalence class. Then $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$ so $x=x'$ and $y-y'=2n\pi$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. Now $y<2\pi$ and $y'\ge 0$, so $y-y'<2\pi-0=2\pi$. Similarly, $y\ge 0$ and $y'<2\pi$, so $y-y'>0-2\pi=-2\pi$. That is, $-2\pi<y-y'<2\pi$, and $y-y'=2n\pi$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$, so $-2\pi<2n\pi<2\pi$. Dividing through by $2\pi$, we see that $-1<n<1$, and $n\in\Bbb Z$, so $n$ must be $0$, and $y=y'$. We already knew that $x=x'$, so $(x,y)=(x',y')$. This shows that an equivalence class cannot contain two different pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ with $0\le y,y'<2\pi$.

To show that each equivalence class does contain such a pair, start with an arbitrary equivalence class $C$, and let $(x,y)$ be any member of $C$. We want to find a pair equivalent to $(x,y)$ whose second element is in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. Any pair equivalent to $(x,y)$ will have $x$ as its first element, so we just have to find its second element. We want a real number $y'\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $y-y'=2n\pi$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. Intuitively it should be clear that such a $y'$ exists: if $y\ge 2\pi$, we just keep subtracting $2\pi$ until we get into the interval $[0,2\pi)$, and if $y<0$, we keep adding $2\pi$ until we do so. The problem is to make this rigorous; the trick is to write $y$ as an integer multiple of $2\pi$ plus a remainder that’s less than $2\pi$.

Let $z=\frac{y}{2\pi}$, and let $n=\lfloor z\rfloor$, the greatest integer less than or equal to $z$. Then $n\le z<n+1$, so $2\pi n\le 2\pi z<2\pi(n+1)$, i.e., $2n\pi\le y<2(n+1)\pi$. Let $y'=y-2n\pi$; clearly $y=2n\pi+y'$, and $0\le y'<2\pi$. You should have no trouble verifying that $(x,y')\sim(x,y)$ and hence that $(x,y')$ is a member of $C$ whose second element is in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. That will show that each equivalence class has at least one such member, and together with the previous result will show that each equivalence class has exactly one such member.